# How to convert String like "June 20, 2019" to Date format in order to Selct a date Range

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6, jet

I have a Access table which contains the Strings like the following:

```
  Date Created                Date Modified
  January 31, 2019            January 31, 2019
  March 08, 2019              March 09, 2019
  April 19, 2019              April 23, 2019
```

I want to be able to select a Date Range between 2 dates using a sql query.

I am using the `Jet4.0` engine and `VB6`.

Any help is greatly appreciated

I have tried this:

But this does not delete any records.

```
Set cijb = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(PathCIJB())

   DELETE Job.* FROM Job WHERE(Job.DateModified >= 'January 03, 2019' ) AND 
   (Job.DateModified <= 'February 05, 2019' )

  Set rs = cijb.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

I expect to delete all the records Modified for example from 
`March 09, 2019` to `April 23, 2019`

Comment: What is the data type of `date modified`?

Comment: You should at once convert those text fields to fields of data type DateTime. As is, it will only cause you forever troubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You comparing strings with strings. And there is no conditions when 'J' comes before 'F', so `WHERE` is always `false`.

Before compare you should do explicit convertation by `CDate` function:

> CDate recognizes date formats according to the locale setting of your
>   system. The correct order of day, month, and year may not be
>   determined if it is provided in a format other than one of the
>   recognized date settings. In addition, a long date format is not
>   recognized if it also contains the day-of-the-week string.

Also to run SQL command query you can not use `OpenRecordset`:

```vb
    Set cijb = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(PathCIJB())

    cijb.Execute "DELETE Job.* FROM Job " & _ 
                 "WHERE (CDate(Job.DateModified) >= CDate('January 03, 2019')) AND (CDate(Job.DateModified) <= CDate('February 05, 2019'));"
```

Comment: Thank you evne though I have not tries your solution I believe it will get e what I need. I appreciate the help